# How to get the size of each linked file in a list with wget?

Tags: list, wget, filesize

I have a list.txt where there's a file link per line. Need a command that shows me the size of each file, in either bytes or human readable format.

Comment: This may be a good start http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/61132/how-do-i-use-wget-with-a-list-of-urls-and-their-corresponding-output-files

Comment: I need a concrete answer please.

Answer (score 1):

This is to show a single file size in bytes:

```
wget --spider url 2>&1 | grep -o -P '(?<=Length: ).*(?= \()'
```

This is to write to a text file the size of each file from a link list file. Note that the resulting file will only be populated when the process ends.

```
wget --spider -i list.txt 2>&1 | grep -o -P '(?<=Length: ).*(?= \()' > sizes.txt
```

If you want to write the size each time a file is checked:

```
while read line ; do wget --spider "$line" 2>&1 | grep -o -P '(?<=Length: ).*(?= \()' >> sizes.txt ; done < list.txt
```

To sum up the size in bytes of all links just to the following:

```
awk '{s+=$1} END {print s}' sizes.txt
```